# Swift convert datetime format to another format

Tags: ios, swift

My scenario, I am trying to converting `Oct 31, 2019 5:20 PM  (MMM dd, yyyy)` to `2019-10-31 05:20:00 (yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss)`

> String DateTime: Oct 29, 2019 11:00 PM
>
> Need to convert: "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter() // Converting 2019-10-29 to Oct 29, 2019
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    let yourDate = formatter.date(from: fullDate)
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"
    let myStringafd = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
    print(myStringafd)
```

Comment: Which date formatter line?

Comment: @Magnas `let dateres = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)` and also trying to printing values of `dateres`

Comment: Is your expected output another string or a date object? Why are you using a pattern that is not relevant neither to the input or the expected output?

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this page](https://nsdateformatter.com/) to figure out the correct pattern.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I didn't get idea. Could you please tell me how to convert `Oct 31, 2019 5:20 PM  (MMM dd, yyyy) Convert to 2019-10-31 05:20:00 (yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because your datestring format and the format in which you want to convert is different. Change the dateFormat to dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"

Here is the code:-

```
let dateString = "2020-05-01 11:00 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier: "en_GB")
let dateres = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
print(dateres)
```

Comment: Can I convert `Oct 29, 2019 11:00 PM` to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a` Could you please update your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first create `date` from the available `date` string. And then convert it back to `string` with the required `dateFormat` as below,

```
let dateString = "Oct 29, 2019 11:00 PM" // Or "Oct 31, 2019 5:20 PM"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy hh:mm a"
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
let stringTodate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

print(stringTodate!.description(with: dateFormatter.locale)) //Tuesday, 29 October 2019 at 23:00:00

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
let finalDate = dateFormatter.string(from: stringTodate!)
print(finalDate) // 2019-10-29 11:00:00

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a"
let finalDate1 = dateFormatter.string(from: stringTodate!)
print(finalDate1) // 2019-10-29 11:00 pm
```

Comment: I am little bit confusion. Can you update your answer, how to convert `Oct 31, 2019 5:20 PM  (MMM dd, yyyy) to 2019-10-31 05:20:00 (yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss)`

Comment: @DebSaga Did you try the above code? You only need to put `Oct 31, 2019 5:20 PM` instead of `Oct 29, 2019 11:00 PM` in the first line.

Comment: I am getting error at `print(stringTodate!.description(with: dateFormatter.locale))` - Error `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: You are tempering with `dateFormat` or providing `dateString` with different date string. Please include your tried code in your question. If you try the above code as it is, you will get the same results. The error you mentioned is because `dateFormatter` is not able to create a valid date because dateFormat and provided dateString are not matching the same format.